# Kotlin Koans: Operator overloading

Tags: kotlin

I'm completing Kotlin Koans's [Comparison](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Conventions/Comparison/Task.kt) exercise and am wondering why `compareTo()` is the function being overriden but `compare()` is the function being used.

How do the two functions relate here?

```
data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int) : Comparable<MyDate> {
    override fun compareTo(otherDate: MyDate): Int = when {
        year != otherDate.year -> year - otherDate.year
        month != otherDate.month -> month - otherDate.month
        else -> dayOfMonth - otherDate.dayOfMonth
    }
}

fun compare(date1: MyDate, date2: MyDate) = date1 < date2
```

Comment: You always override the base class methods of the custom object type. The Comparable<MyDate> which is the interface here is the reason why it is overriding. The compare function in the above code is a separate function which can be used as it is declared in the same code file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compare()` function there just a placeholder shows "how to use `compareTo()`" without actual meaning. You can change it to other names as you want.

> How do the two functions relate here?

A randomly named function `compare()` calls `MyDate`'s `compareTo()` function **with the comparator symbol `<`**.